# Date to character with specific format

Tags: r, string, date

This seems like a really easy question, but 30 mins of Googling didn't solve it:

How can I convert a Date (YYYY-MM-DD) to a character with the typical American format (MM/DD/YYYY)? In other words, I know I can use as.Date(dt, format = "%Y-%m-%d") to specify the format of the input date, but how can I specify the format of the output??

```
dt = "2013-04-19"
as.Date(dt, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2013-04-19" #### NOT what I want
as.character(as.Date(dt, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
[1] "2013-04-19" #### Also NOT what I want

"04/19/2013" Is what I want
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
format(as.Date(dt, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "04/19/2013"
```

Comment: That works, many thanks! I had tried format(dt, "%m/%d/%Y") but it threw an error

Comment: Yeah, `dt` has to be `Date`/`POSIXct`/`POSIXlt` in order to allow for datetime component extraction/formatting (in your example, `dt` is character)